# Loop through data and add all values where the 'Year' is the same

Tags: php, loops

To start things of simply I'm just going to give the input and then the output of what I need.

I have 2 variables looping until there is no more data, `$year` and `$profit`.

```
_________________________
Year              Profit

2011              23.42
2011              253.23
2011              54.5
2012              433.23
2012              53.2
2013              11.4
2013              45.5
2013              532.1
```

I was wondering what the best approach would be to add together all the values where the year is the same, so it would look like this:

```
_________________________
Year              Profit

2011              331.15
2012              486.42
2013              589
```

I've tried `arrays` but I always end up getting an `Undefined Index` error. I would post an example but there is too many variables and too much going on for anyone to understand straight up.

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this!

Comment: does this input come from a database?

Comment: @Garytje: yes, but im limited to code this in `php`, i cant just group them in the `sql` query :(

Comment: "I would post an example but there is too many variables and too much going on for anyone to understand straight up." Would suggest you need to re factor your code

Comment: Show the code you've tried.

Comment: @chriz, i've never had someone having acces to php but not to the refactoring of an SQL statement..

Comment: @Garytje: its for my job, they told me not to do it in the sql ha

Comment: `SELECT YEAR(date_column) AS year, SUM(profit) AS total FROM myTable GROUP BY YEAR(date_column)` and you can use that on your PHP ;)

Comment: @chriz, so you get paid for problems you don't know how to fix, you ask it here. I had a coworker like that once.. he's gone now. Stand up and say they're wrong. They'll HAVE to appreciate it, i know i would!

Comment: @Garytje: wise words :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I assume `$year` and `$profit` are the same length and ordered correctly by index you could do it like this:

```
$year = array(2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013);
$profit = array(23.42, 253.23, 54.5, 433.23, 53.2, 11.4, 45.5, 532.1);

$sums = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($year); $i++) {
    if (isset($sums[$year[$i]])) {
        $sums[$year[$i]] += $profit[$i];
    } else {
        $sums[$year[$i]] = $profit[$i];
    }
}

print_r($sums);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [2011] => 331.15
    [2012] => 486.43
    [2013] => 589
)
```

Comment: +1 for giving the correct answer even though op uses the wrong technique

Comment: Hi! Did my answer help you? I would appreciate if you could accept the answer if it did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $value) {
    if (isset($result[$value['year']])) {
        $result[$value['year']] += $value['profit'];
    } else {
        $result[$value['year']] = $value['profit'];
    }
}
```

Comment: he has 2 different variables, $year and $profit, no related keys / ids

Comment: It seems that he gets data from db. So they should be in the same rows or should be another associations betwee this data. Difficaul to predict :)

Comment: @Garytje he doesn't need any keys / ids he wants to group by year and what he listed on the question seemed to be a db output.